# Finding the probability distribution in a Poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

A pedestrian wishes to cross a one-way street where cars pass by according to a Poisson process with rate $10$ per minute. The pedestrian will only cross when there are no cars for $10$ seconds. If the pedestrian arrives at the stop at a random time, what's the probability distribution for the number of cars that will pass before you can cross?

---

I did hear about memorylessness of Poisson Process, so the result should reflect that, but I'm new to Poisson processes so I cannot solve this one.

I know the number of cars that pass by has rate $10/60 = 1/6$ per second. So we want to find the expected time for $10$ arrivals. Let $N(t)$ be the number of arrivals that have occured by time $t$. Then I think we want $P(\min\{t' \mid N(t) = 10'\} \leq t')$.

But this looks really messy. Maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: The inter-arrival time of a Poisson process is exponential, and they are i.i.d. The pedestrian will cross the road when the inter-arrival time is greater than $10$ second, and you can compute this probability. So what is the distribution of the number of i.i.d. Bernoulli trials until you get the first success?

Comment: It is geometric. But I am still unsure about how to compute this. I have never done a problem with Poisson process before. I read about the Poisson process chapter three times in Ross but I am still struggling

Comment: @BGM I think I might have gotten somewhere with your hint. I did $P(\text{some inter-arrival time} \geq 10) = e^{-\lambda x} = e^{-100/60}$. If $Y$ is the number of cars passed, then $P(Y = y) = e^{-100}(1 - e^{-100})^{y - 1}$, so $Y \sim Geometric(e^{-100/60})$. Is that right?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks. The second part to this question is "What property of Poisson processes did you use?" -- This would be independent increments, right?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$ and fix $T>0$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(N(T)=n) = e^{-\lambda T}\frac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!},\ n=0,1,2,\ldots.
$$
Here $\lambda=\frac16$ and $T=10$ so we have
$$
\mathbb P(N(10)=n) = e^{-\frac16\cdot10}\frac{\left(\frac16\cdot10\right)^n}{n!} = e^{-\frac53}\frac{\left(\frac53\right)^n}{n!},\ n=0,1,2,\ldots.
$$